# In how many ways can we arrange 7 different things to 3 people all of them must get at least one.

Tags: permutations

> In how many ways can we arrange 7 different things to 3 people. All of them must get at least one.

**My Approach**

I used the formula (n-$1$)C(r-$1$)=$6$C$2$=$15$

> But I am confused will it work for different things also?

Comment: You are right, you cannot use the formula for different things.

Comment: This does not work. I would be tempted to use Inclusion/Exclusion. There is a more awkward approach using cases, and a fancier approach using Stirling numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you guide how to solve.As i was unable to guide by your hint.What is exactly inclusive/exclusive principle.Where exactly I can apply these?

Comment: From $3^7$, subtract the $\binom{3}{1}2^7$ ways to give to two people, but this overcompensates for the ways to give all to one. Total $3^7-\binom{3}{1}2^7+\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I have not understood your question?

Comment: There is an accepted answer already, which is fully correct in outline, with some of the numerical work omitted. The number of "bad" ways to distribute (one or two people get nothing) is $\binom{3}{1}2^7-\binom{3}{2}1^7$.  So the final answer is $2187-384+3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Each object has 3 options, as each object can go to either of the three objects. This means that there are a total of $3^7$ options.
Now, subtract the cases in which there is at least one person with zero objects.

Comment: I think that would be 1 case with zero objects.So,Ans would be $3^7$ -$1$.

Comment: @justintakro Think again! There are 3 people that can have zero objects, one at a time. Moreover, they can also have zero objects 2 at a time. Meaning that there can be 3 cases when 1 person has zero objects. How many cases are there when 2 people have zero objects?

Comment: "There are 3 people that can have zero objects, one at a time"Does this mean  either A can have(then B and C does not have) or B can have(then A and C does not have) or C can have(then B and A does not have).Either A and B do not have (C has),B and C do not have(A has),A and C do not have(B has).

Comment: @Grummy bears Ans given is $381$.I do not get correct Ans here.

Comment: @justintakro That answer seems incorrect...  Are you sure it's not 2181?